# Can I use a Modified Z-score with skewed and non-normal data?

Tags: machine-learning, standard-deviation, normality-assumption, z-score

As per z-score it assumes data comes from normal distribution, Modified z-score can work with data that is skewed. My question is it good to use modified z-score for a data that is not normal?

Comment: What does it mean to be skewed but follow normality? In my mind, normality precludes skewness, and skewness precludes normality. // What do you mean by a "modified z-score"? // You're always allowed to calculate $z_i = \dfrac{x_i -\bar x}{s}$.

Comment: So, Modified z-score doesn't use standard deviation as denominator, it uses Median absolute deviation, instead of mean it uses median.

Comment: Sure, use that transformation: $$z^*_i = \dfrac{x_i - \text{median}(x)}{MAD(X)}$$ It will give you an empirical distribution with zero median and MAD equal to one. However, how do you want to use it? Are you trying to transform data for a machine learning model?

Comment: I want to use it for outlier detection. https://hwbdocuments.env.nm.gov/Los%20Alamos%20National%20Labs/TA%2054/11587.pdf from this but I am not sure whether it can be used for non-normal data?

Comment: Outlier detection is fraught with problems, and we have had many good discussions on Cross Validated concerning that topic.